# PHP Curly bracket variable not replaced when used as an argument in a function

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is create a reusable gallery function where the layout of the thumbnails can be changed if necessary.

My problem is that my $thumbLayout string with curly bracket variables, doesn't work when included in the function like this, it only works when the string is written after the replacing variables.

Would really appreciate any help with coming up with a solution or better way of doing this.

```
$thumbLayout = "<div class=\"customgallery\"><img src=\"{$thumbImgPath}\" width=\{$width}\" height=\"{$height}\" alt=\"{$imgName}\" /></div>";

function createImageGallery($galleryName,$db,$thumbLayout=''){
        $imgno = 1;
        //Page numbers//
        if(isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }elseif(isset($_POST['page']) && is_numeric($_POST['page'])) {
            $page = $_POST['page'];
        }else{
            $page = 1;
        }

        $rowGallery = $db->query_first("SELECT gallery_id,num_cols,images_per_page FROM tblgallery WHERE gallery_name='$galleryName' AND show_gallery='y' LIMIT 1");    
        if($rowGallery!=false){
            $recordsPerPage = $rowGallery['images_per_page'];
            $numCol = $rowGallery['num_cols'];
            $gallery = '<ul>';
            $gallery_id = $rowGallery['gallery_id'];

            $offset = ($page - 1) * $recordsPerPage;
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tblimages WHERE group_id='$gallery_id' AND imgpath_thumb<>'' AND show_img='y' ORDER BY img_order";
                $rs = $db->query("$query LIMIT $offset,$recordsPerPage");
                foreach($rs as $row){
                    $largeImgPath = '/'.$row['imgpath_large'];
                    $imgName = $row['img_name'];
                    $thumbImgPath = '/'.$row['imgpath_thumb'];
                    if(($imgno>1) && (!is_float(($imgno-1)/$numCol))){
                        $li_class = 'class="newline"';
                    }elseif(($imgno>1) && (!is_float(($imgno)/$numCol))){
                        $li_class = 'class="last"'; 
                    }else{
                        $li_class = ''; 
                    }
                    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($row['imgpath_thumb']);
                    if($thumbLayout==''){
                        $gallery .= '<li '.$li_class.'><a href="'.$largeImgPath.'" class="popup" title="'.$imgName.'"><div class="gallery_imgbox"><img src="'.$thumbImgPath.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" alt="'.$imgName.'" /></div><span>'.$imgno.$imgName.'</span></a></li>';
                    }else{
                        $gallery .= '<li '.$li_class.'>'.$thumbLayout.'</li>';
                    }
                    $imgno++;
                }
            $gallery .= '</ul>';
        }else{
            //Gallery specified does not exist//
            return 'Gallery does not exist';
        }
    return  $gallery;
}
```

I think it is really to do with the placement of the $thumbLayout.
When inside the function below the replacement variables it works, but when included from outside the function they don't get replaced.
OK so here's a really simple example:

```
$test1 = sprintf("My name is %s.",$name);
$test2 = "My name is {$name}.";
$test3 = "My name is ${name}.";
$test4 = "My name is $name .";
$test5 = "My name is <?= name ?>.";
$test6 = "My name is {{name}} .";

function showtest($test){
$name = "Bob";
echo $test; 
}

showtest($test1); //Result: My name is .//
showtest($test2); //Result: My name is .//
showtest($test3); //Result: My name is .//
showtest($test4); //Result: My name is .//
showtest($test5); //Result: My name is .//
showtest($test6); //Result: My name is {{name}}.//
```

Whereas this will work (but doesn't help me)

```
function showtest2(){
$name = "Bob";
$test = "My name is {$name}.";  
echo $test; 
}

showtest2(); //Result: My name is Bob.//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$thumbLayout = "<div class=\"customgallery\"><img src=\"${thumbImgPath}\" width=\"${width}\" height=\"${height}\" alt=\"${imgName}\" /></div>";
```

Braces will be replaced by PHP if the left brace { is after the $ sign, ie, ${varname}.

## ADDED:

One should put the variable $thumbLayout inside the sub-routine:

Your function has to be like this:

```
<?php
function createImageGallery($galleryName,$db){
    $imgno = 1;
    //Page numbers//
    if(isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }elseif(isset($_POST['page']) && is_numeric($_POST['page'])) {
        $page = $_POST['page'];
    }else{
        $page = 1;
    }

    $rowGallery = $db->query("SELECT gallery_id,num_cols,images_per_page FROM tblgallery WHERE gallery_name='$galleryName' AND show_gallery='y' LIMIT 1");    
    if($rowGallery!=false){
        $recordsPerPage = $rowGallery['images_per_page'];
        $numCol = $rowGallery['num_cols'];
        $gallery = '<ul>';
        $gallery_id = $rowGallery['gallery_id'];

        $offset = ($page - 1) * $recordsPerPage;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tblimages WHERE group_id='$gallery_id' AND imgpath_thumb<>'' AND show_img='y' ORDER BY img_order";
            $rs = $db->query("$query LIMIT $offset,$recordsPerPage");
            foreach($rs as $row){
                $largeImgPath = '/'.$row['imgpath_large'];
                $imgName = $row['img_name'];
                $thumbImgPath = '/'.$row['imgpath_thumb'];
                if(($imgno>1) && (!is_float(($imgno-1)/$numCol))){
                    $li_class = 'class="newline"';
                }elseif(($imgno>1) && (!is_float(($imgno)/$numCol))){
                    $li_class = 'class="last"'; 
                }else{
                    $li_class = ''; 
                }
                list($width, $height) = getimagesize($row['imgpath_thumb']);

$thumbLayout = "<div class=\"customgallery\"><img src=\"${thumbImgPath}\" width=\"${width}\" height=\"${height}\" alt=\"${imgName}\" /></div>";

                if($thumbLayout==''){
                    $gallery .= '<li '.$li_class.'><a href="'.$largeImgPath.'" class="popup" title="'.$imgName.'"><div class="gallery_imgbox"><img src="'.$thumbImgPath.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" alt="'.$imgName.'" /></div><span>'.$imgno.$imgName.'</span></a></li>';
                }else{
                    $gallery .= '<li '.$li_class.'>'.$thumbLayout.'</li>';
                }
                $imgno++;
            }
        $gallery .= '</ul>';
    }else{
        //Gallery specified does not exist//
        return 'Gallery does not exist';
    }
return  $gallery;
}

//
// then in the main body:
//
// ....
//

$host = "localhost";
$database = "picassoreserve";
$user = "johndoe2";
$pass = "mypassword";

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $pass);
//
// or 
// $db = @new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);
//

$galleryName = "picasso";

echo createImageGallery($galleryName, $db);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies but still nothing working.

Comment: I have setup a simpler example, none of the below work, $name is always blank:

    $test1 = sprintf("My name is %s.",$name);
    $test2 = "My name is {$name}.";
    $test3 = "My name is ${name}.";
    $test4 = "My name is $name .";
    $test5 = "My name is <?= name ?>.";
    $test6 = "My name is {{name}} .";

    function showtest($test){
 $name = "Bob";
 echo $test; 
    }

Comment: Please Try this: put $thumbLayout = "<div class=\"customgallery\"><img src=\"${thumbImgPath}\" width=\"${width}\" height=\"${height}\" alt=\"${imgName}\" /></div>"; inside the function body, then call it in the main body: createImageGallery($galleryName,$db,$thumbLayout);

Comment: Thanks jacouh, but if I put $thumbLayout in the body, how would I change the layout of the thumbnails for each different gallery? I wanted to make the code re-usable for as many different layouts as possible.

I may just have to look at a "replace" instead, but thought there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: I took a quick look and see that your customizing parameters are read in the MySQL db. So your gallery is defined through this db: width, height, etc... What did you want to customize in more ?

Comment: As PHP function cannot access directly a global variables here thumbLayout. You can read/assign a global variable in a sub-routine through: assign $GLOBALS["thumbLayout"] = "abc"; or read echo $GLOBALS["thumbLayout"];

Comment: Yes so the image name, sizes, paths etc. are pulling from the db, but what i was hoping to change on the fly was the layout i.e. a product image might have buy now buttons, images might have links to specified pages or just a class/id triggering opening a "colorbox" etc.

Comment: At the moment, all params you used to get $thumbLayout are db specifed and local variables in the sub-routine: $thumbImgPath, $width, $height, $imgName, so $thumbLayout has to be calculated inside the sub-function. In the future if you want to add a link, "Add to cart" button, you shall modify the assignment of $thumbLayout in the function body. Or add more fields in the db table to specified them.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time jacouh, not what I was hoping for but I think you're correct that the only way of specifying the layout is within the function body.

Comment: With great pleasure. We use also in our site some gallery like this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to have the curly braces at all.

```
$thumbLayout = "<div class=\"customgallery\"><img src=\"$thumbImgPath\" width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\" alt=\"$imgName\" /></div>";
```

Will work well.  You might prefer to use:

```
$thumbLayout = sprintf("<div class=\"customgallery\"><img src=\"%s\" width=\"%s\" height=\"%s\" alt=\"s\" /></div>",$thumbImgPath,$width,$height,$imgName);
```

which will also work if you change your variables to arrays, say the result of a mysql query.  This is the method I use as I feel the small loss of readability and the higher risk of introducing bugs by wrongly ordering the variables is made up for by the ability to insert the results of functions, arrays and variables easily.  With careful formatting and practice, errors are less common.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want something that works like what you get in a template file, where we find template variables that commonly look like `{{my_var}}` or `<?= $my_var ?>`

Unfortunately, here your curly braces variables will be replaced as soon as you assign it `=` to $thumbLayout, and not after you've passed it into the function. It does not work the way templates do.